# identical contact forms behaving differently on different hosting accounts

Tags: php, html, forms, web-hosting

I've never experienced this problem. I have two hosting accounts, one with godaddy, and one with hostgator. There are identical files on these two URLS:

http://www.cloth2clay.com

and

http://www.vitaminjdesign.com/cloth/cloths/

Both websites look the same, but there is one major difference. When filling out the contact form on the second link, it works correctly and gets sent to me. One the first link, you press submit, and the success message doesnt show up and the mail is never sent. It doesnt work!  The files are IDENTICAL. it makes no sense to me. The contact form is PHP and ajax. Perhaps its something on godaddys backend? Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to debug the PHP script or post it here. It's impossible to tell without.

Comment: there are three PHP files, contact.php functions.php and config.php. They are all located in the root folder. They are too long to post here. Any other way?

Comment: You can use a site like http://pastebin.ca to post the files and then link.

Comment: Not using GoDaddy hosting would probably be the easiest solution to this and many other problems you have yet to experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the configuration settings (or even the version) for PHP and/or its modules differ between the two hosting services. Try creating a script that has only the following in it:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

And viewing it in a browser; you can then compare the settings for both.

Comment: ok, you might be on to something. THe working version has a PHP version of 5.2.11 and the non working version is 4.3.11. So Im guessing I have to call them to update it?

Answer (score 0):

> the mail is never sent

You're emailing the form? I'm guessing [GoDaddy doesn't support `mail()`](http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA336CA336&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=godaddy+php+mail).